# I need formula to get the sum of specific KPI for main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

master data

[image] main sheet

trying to get the data from master sheet for the colors as mentioned for main sheet from master sheet for the above mentioned kpi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: In Excel, you can't make a formula, based on a colour.

Answer (score 0):

there is no formula for color based operation in excel. You can try using combination of vlookup and hlookup formula to get data from a vertical-horizontal tabular data set.